# Rails Strong Parameters - Not passing through array parameter even when permitted as correct type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Using Ruby on Rails (5.1.4), I'm attempting to pass an array of IDs to a controller while optionally nesting the array within a hash with the controller's name. My params method is as follows:

```
  def operator_params
    params.fetch(:operator, {}).permit(ids: [])
  end
```

And an example JSON body attached to the request could be (although I have also tried with putting the array in the URL):

```
{
    "ids": ["asd"]
}
```

Rails sees the parameters: `Parameters: {"ids"=>["asd"], "id"=>"570158bb-428d-4e55-b55a-a94d1515c24a", "operator"=>{}}`, but still filters them out.

The result of `ap operator_params` is `{}`.

Am I missing something obvious?

The strange thing is that I am using similar logic elsewhere in my app: `params.fetch(:flight, {}).permit(..., :ids)`, which doesn't even declare the array type as is typically required, but works fine.

---

Update: My understanding of .fetch was a little off it seems, it should have been:

```
def operator_params
  params.fetch(:operator, params).permit(ids: [])
end
```

Which *should* allow you to submit either `{"operator": {"ids": []}}` or `{"ids": []}` and accept either. However, this still just doesn't seem to be working with the array. This method will accept the former (nested under `operator`), while:

```
def operator_params
  params.permit(ids: [])
end
```

will accept the latter (without the nesting), as you'd expect. According to the description on [the rails API doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/fetch), including a second parameter (i.e. `params`) will use that value if the `operator` key is missing, so it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters: {"ids"=>["asd"], "id"=>"570158bb-428d-4e55-b55a-a94d1515c24a", "operator"=>{}}

change it as

Parameters: {"ids"=>["asd", "{"id" => "570158bb-428d-4e55-b55a-a94d1515c24a"}", "{"operator"=>{}}"]}

Answer (score 0):

It is due to your params contains empty hash of `operator`

pass params values as

```
{ "operator"=> { "ids"=>["asd"], "id"=>"570158bb-428d-4e55-b55a-a94d1515c24a" } }
```

Comment: My understanding was that the fetch() method would allow either params nested under operator or not. I'd like to maintain this if possible as other methods in the controller make use of it

Comment: in this case, you need to pass `ids` and `id` inside `operator` key and fetch operator from params